# Python idiom for counting loop execution

Tags: python, for-loop, idioms

If looping over a list/tuple/sequence, you can use `len(...)` to infer how many times the loop was executed. But when looping over an iterator, you cannot.

[*Update for clarity: I am thinking about single-use finite iterators where I want to do computation on the items AND count them at the same time.*]

I currently use an explicit counter variable as in the following example:

```
def some_function(some_argument):
    pass


some_iterator = iter("Hello world")

count = 0
for value in some_iterator:
    some_function(value)
    count += 1

print("Looped %i times" % count)
```

Given there are 11 characters in `"Hello world"`,
the expected output here is:

```
Looped 11 times
```

I have also considered this shorter alternative using `enumerate(...)` but I do not find this as clear:

```
def some_function(some_argument):
    pass


some_iterator = iter("Hello world")

count = 0  # Added for special case, see note below
for count, value in enumerate(some_iterator, start=1):
    some_function(value)

print("Looped %i times" % count)
```

[*Update for reference: @mata spotted that as originally written this second example would fail if the iterator is empty. Inserting `count = 0` solves this, or we can use the `for ... else ...` structure to handle this corner case.*]

It does not use the index from `enumerate(...)` within the loop, but rather setting the variable to the loop count is almost a side effect. To me this is quite unclear, so I prefer the first version with the explicit increment.

Is there an accepted Pythonic way to do this (ideally for both Python 3 and Python 2 code)?

Comment: Yes, and this solution is `enumerate`. Why do you consider it not as "clear"? I don't know if it is a matter of getting used to it, but `enumerate` seems readable and concise to me...

Comment: It depends... I'd say that the second form is more pythonic, but it also isn't covering the exact same case, because if the iterator has no elements `count` after the loop will not be defined and you get a NameError, so you'd have use a `for ... else` or initialize the counter before the loop.

Comment: Good point @mata, if the iterator was empty the second example as written will fail.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine the convenience of `enumerate` with the counter being defined if the loop did not run by adding one line:

```
count = 0  # Counter is set in any case.
for count, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
   doSomethingTo(item)
print "Did it %d times" % count
```

If all you need it is to count the number of items in an iterator, without doing anything with the items, and without making a list of them, you can do it simply:

```
count = sum(1 for ignored_item in data)  # count a 1 for each item
```

Comment: As written this has an off by one error (by default ``enumerate`` uses ``0`` to ``count - 1``), which is why I had the verbose extra argument to start from one.

Comment: I'm familiar with the list compression trick with sum but in this case I need to do something with the items (represented in the example with ``some_function``).

Comment: @peterjc: Good catch, thanks! I've updated my answer with `start=1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all sorts of stuff to count the number of items in a generator, but in any case, the original generator will be wasted. Exhausted, to be precise.

```
length = sum(1 for x in gen)
length = max(c for c, _ in enumerate(gen, 1))
length = len(list(gen))
```

1. The first way shown here is really nice as it handles the case with an empty generator well and returns zero as expected.
2. The second code will raise an exception when given an exhausted generator, which may be useful when it should never be exhausted, but it actually is, so the execution will stop and you'll be able to investigate what went wrong.
3. This code will probably waste a lot of memory if the data provided by `gen` is too big, but it's just easy to understand, so that nobody will have to think hard banging their head against a wall trying to understand what this means.

All of these will work only for finite generators.

If you want to calculate the 'length' of the iterator *while looping over it*, you can do this:

```
length = 0
for length, data in enumerate(gen, 1):
    # do stuff
```

Now, `length` will be equal to the number of elements the generator has produced. Notice that you don't have to increment `length` manually as both `length` and `data` are still available and valid after the loop execution.

---

EDIT: if you want to execute some function for each value *and disregard its return value* (you can handle it by using a list as one of the function's arguments), you can try this:

```
length = sum(1 | bool(function(x)) for x in gen)
```

This will calculate the length while applying `function` to each element of the generator. Still, using `enumerate` looks like a better idea.

Comment: None of your examples allow for running code using the items in the generator (which could be something expensive to run, or single use), but you end with endorsing the ``enumerate`` approach.

Comment: @peterjc, I've added an example of how you can incorporate function application into one of my initial solutions.

Comment: That's an inventive generator expression approach combining counting with calling the function on each item, but as a matter of taste I find it too complicated. The nature of my question means judging alternatives was always going to be subjective.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the number of items in an iterator. Think of this case

```
def gen():
   a = 1
   while True:
       yield a
       a += 1
f = gen()

for value in f:
    # do something
```

What is the size of this iterator? An iterator ends when, and *if*, it raises a `StopIteration`. On the contrary, when you iterate over a sequence, the sequence already exists, so its length can be known.

Both of the approaches you used are fine. *best* depends on your taste. Another option would be to use

```
from itertools import count
for item, counter in zip(iterator, count()):
    # do stuff
```

However, I think in most cases your first, traditional approach would be clearer.

Comment: This is a good example for explaining why I am asking this question - I glossed over this in the introduction just noting you can't use ``len(...)`` on an iterator. But your answer does not answer my question, which is how best to count the number of items in the iterator assuming you are using it in a for loop.

Comment: @peterjc: ok, just pointing out that it's not possible. edited the question

Comment: Thanks - that's clearer now. I agree the "best" approach is going to be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this?

```
len(list(some_iterator))
```

Comment: It does work but reads all elements of `some_iterator` into memory.